# Untrusted touch events are blocked Android 12

Tags: android-12

My app is affected due to [untrusted touch events](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all?hl=nb#untrusted-touch-events) introduced by android in Android 12. If i understand it correctly problem is majorly due to using of the flag `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`, so I removed all the occurrences

```
08-20 16:10:45.752  1716  2206 D InputDispatcher: Stack of obscuring windows during untrusted touch (705, 1575):
08-20 16:10:45.752  1716  2206 D InputDispatcher:     * type=2038, package=xxxxxxx, id=204, mode=USE_OPACITY, alpha=1.00, frame=[0,145][1080,2296], touchableRegion=[0,145][1080,2296], window={36c5ada , flags={NOT_FOCUSABLE | NOT_TOUCHABLE | NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN | HARDWARE_ACCELERATED}, inputFeatures={0x0}, hasToken=true, applicationInfo.name=, applicationInfo.token=<null>
```

Still the NOT_TOUCHABLE flag is not going! There is only one [write up](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/untrusted-touch-events-2c0e0b9c374c) available as of now on the subject and my case falls in 'Unnecessarily large windows' in this blog. i.e. my window is already `wrap_content` and i have removed any occurrence of `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`. Still my touches are being blocked. How i know my touches work fine otherwise? As recommended by the developer.android site when i run following command `adb shell settings put global block_untrusted_touches 2`, everything seems to be working just fine. Any help would be highly appreciated!